# ViewPager doesn't scroll vertically when is inside a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm making and android app where the main activity consists in a TabLayout and a ViewPager, a Floating action button is needed to start another activity, the problem is that when I add a CoordinatorLayout the ViewPager doesn't scroll (The viewPager contains 3 fragments one with a RecyclerView and the other two contains just textview with a lot of text, so all of them must scroll vertically.

The ViewPager works perfectly, but when I put it inside a CoordinatorLayout is not possible to do vertical scroll in any of the fragments loaded in the ViewPager.

I tried to add android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" in every fragment root layout but it doesn't work.

EDIT: 
All of the fragments loaded in the ViewPager have ScrollView as Root view.
This is my Main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

                />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/TabLayoutPrincipal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"/>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/ViewPagerPrincipal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                />



        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addShotFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is what inside of the fragment with the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecViewTomas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The another fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of  (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum,  comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham."/>

    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You should add a `ScrollView` in the fragments that need vertical scrolling

Comment: Yeah, all fragments are inside of a ScrollView

Comment: Could you post the XML of the fragment that is not scrolling, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think `AppBarLayout` has issues with nested scrolling views, because it wasn't intended to be parent for viewgroups with nested scroll.
But you can change your layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

                />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/TabLayoutPrincipal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/ViewPagerPrincipal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addShotFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

so, ViewPager becomes child of `CoordinatorLayout` not `AppBarLayout` and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved doing these changes to the layout:

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

                />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/TabLayoutPrincipal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"/>




        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/ViewPagerPrincipal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            />


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addShotFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```